# Using 'timeupdate' event to implement video subtitles change

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web video player with custom implementation of subtitles support (no WebVTT allowed). I have the subtitles data fetched and converted:

```
const subtitles = [{
  min: 8, // appear time in sec
  max: 12, // disappear time in sec
  text: 'some txt'
}, ...]
```

So in order to update the subtitles container, I came up with something like this:

```
  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
    const textToDisplay = SH.findSubtitle(video.currentTime); // searches the subtitles array
    SH.render(textToDisplay);
  });
```

It works of course, but is it a good idea to run this on every 'timeupdate' event emission? What would be a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: A better approach? What about you use the standard and built-in way instead of doing it yourself? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API

Comment: I would love to,  but as I wrote - I cannot use WebVVT.

Comment: Missed that... Now wondering why it's "Not allowed"... Otherwise, yes listening to timeupdate is the best you can do. But indeed it will fire quite often so you might want to optimize your handler there (i.e you could store the next frame change schedule only once, and then only compare the current time against this stored value, and only if you have passed this stored value will you call the *findSubtitle* method again, to store the next one and finally render it (only once). This should release a bit of computation, but you'd also have to add a new listener on the *seeked* event.

Comment: i think it's a good idea

Comment: @Kaiido, it's not allowed because that's a recruitment task :).

Comment: ... recruitment tasks that prevent you from using the right tools ...

Comment: probably to check how well I know JS or my way of thinking. Anyway, will post a solution that I will come up with, in case someone applies to the same company in the future ;).